# selected value multicolumn combobox c# dektop application

Tags: c#

I am creating a desktop application.
I have MultiColumn combobox control on my form ,on which when user click a datagrid comes as a popup which contains four columns.
what i want that,when user select  any row of datagrid , i get value of any one column of that selected row.
Is their any way.

Answer (score 0):

You add handle [DataGrid.CurrentCellChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.currentcellchanged.aspx) event

```
// Create an instance of the 'CurrentCellChanged' EventHandler.
private void CallCurrentCellChanged()
{
   myDataGrid.CurrentCellChanged += new EventHandler(Grid_CurCellChange);
}

// Raise the event when focus on DataGrid cell changes.
private void Grid_CurCellChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // String variable used to show message.
   string myString = "CurrentCellChanged event raised, cell focus is at ";
  // Get the co-ordinates of the focussed cell.
  var value=  myDataGrid[myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber,myDataGrid.CurrentCell.RowNumber].Value
```

}